# How to quickly find / go to declaration of getter and setter for a field?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse IDE, when I am within a class file, one of the class attributes is used in some methods of that class.

How can I quickly go to the declarations of the getter and setter for that attribute without scrolling through the whole class file?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field > <kbd>Open call hierachy</kbd>

or select the field then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Another solution is to activate the `Toggle mark occurences` option from the menu bar or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. That will put small marks on the right side of your window, next to the scroll bar. Note that will mark every use of the field in the file but it's not always easy to distinguish the marks from the research mark results and the other types of marks used by Eclipse (errors, warning, TODO, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + click on the field gets you to the declaration

Ctrl + O and you can start typing a method and go to it

Ctrl +  g on the field finds where it is used and the getter/setter will be in the list

There might be other ways but a good source would be to read Eclipse Shortcuts and find the ones that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One way is a quick outline

> ctrl+o (cmd+o)

or search via

> ctrl + h